# File to import not found or unreadable: susy

Tags: compass-sass, susy-compass

I just can't figure out what is wrong with my setup with Susy. 
I am on OS X 10.7.4

I have followed along here: http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/getting-started/

Error

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: susy.
Load paths:
Users/simon/Websites/wpsvntree/trunk/sass
/Users/simon/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.7/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
/Users/simon/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/compass-0.11.7/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
            Compass::SpriteImporter
on line 2 of /Users/simon/Websites/wpsvntree/trunk/sass/_base.sass
from line 2 of /Users/simon/Websites/wpsvntree/trunk/sass/screen.sass
```

My installed Gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

chunky_png (1.2.6, 1.2.5)
compass (0.12.2, 0.11.7)
compass-boilerplate-plugin (0.1.0)
compass-h5bp (0.0.5, 0.0.2)
compass-rails (1.0.3)
fssm (0.2.9, 0.2.8.1)
html5-boilerplate (2.1.0)
sass (3.2.1, 3.1.15)
susy (1.0.3)
```

My config.rb file which is sitting in the root of the project

```
require 'susy' 
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
relative_assets = true
```

_base.scss

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Imports
@import "susy";

/* GRID SETUP
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

$total-columns  : 12;
$column-width   : 4em;
$gutter-width   : 1em;
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width;
$show-grid-backgrounds  : true;
/* SECTION
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

screen.scss

```
 @import "base";
 .container {
  @include container;
  @include susy-grid-background;
 }
```

I ran this command from the directory wpsvntree: `compass create trunk -r susy -u susy` 
**with success**.

then `compass watch trunk/`

Viewing my project I see the first above error.

I can't see where I have gone wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: That does look good. Do any of these issues relate? https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues/search?q=not%20found%20or%20unreadable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Followed the solution here. Fixed.
https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues/21

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Thanks for finding the answer. Might I suggest you accept your own answer so that it will be clearer to others that there is one. The first thing I do when I scroll down through a question is to look for that green check mark.

Comment: I spoke too soon. My problem is slightly different. My error was with the require "susy".  I think moving the config.rb just caused the Compiler not to find it. Now I have the error on the import.

Comment: I'm not using `config.rb` nor `compass` :(

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem and found that my syntax was wrong in my config.rb file. The correct line would be `require "susy"` but I had an equal sign between require and susy, which is wrong.

I hope that helps other noobs out there like myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
gem install compass --pre
```

This  worked for me

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be "the correct answer" I had the same error, and realised I was trying to build with SASS, instead of using the Compass build system.

A bit silly I know, but hopefully if someone makes the same mistake, it could be helpful :D/