# integrating susy suport in anglar2 seed

Tags: node.js, angular, gulp-sass, susy

I had integrated sass suport in angular2 seed (https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) and also installed susy form npm(npm install susy --save-dev) but when I imported susy form .scss file it gives following errors

```
[13:01:16] Starting 'build.html_scss'...
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    src/client/css/main.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~susy
       Parent style sheet: /home/jorin/WebStormWorkSpace/nylndaUI/src/client/css/main.scss
        on line 1 of src/client/css/main.scss
>> @import "~susy";
   ^

[13:01:16] Finished 'build.html_scss' after 218 ms
```

Anybody who can guide me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File to import not found or unreadable: susy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022956/file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-susy)

Comment: You may need to install susy as a rub gem.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022956/file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-susy

Comment: configuring susy to work with config.rb file and compass is working fine but I am trying to figure out how can I use susy with gulp based build system which uses gulp-sass  to load susy(as i guess) and use the susy gird system in my project

Answer (score 3):

In your sass, correct the path to susy.

It could be

```
@import "~susy/sass/susy";
```

The [Susy install Guide suggests to use bower](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/install/) and to use a relative path.

```
bower install susy --save
@import "../bower_components/susy/sass/susy";
```

But there's no reason you couldn't use the path to your npm-installed susy:

```
@import "../node_modules/susy/sass/susy";
```

If you're taking this method, this file is relative to your sass file, so it could be something like

```
@import "../../../../node_modules/susy/sass/susy";
```