# Error: File to import not found or unreadable: susy

Tags: gruntjs, susy

Having looked at, [File to import not found or unreadable: susy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022956/file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-susy), I was unable to get the answer.

My Partial gruntfile.js

```
sass: {
   options: {
      /** Only use include_paths if extracting elements from Node_Modules */
      includePaths: ['node_modules/susy/sass']
            }, //options
            dist: {
                options: {
                    outputStyle: 'expanded',
                    sourceMap: false,
                    require: 'susy'
                },
                files: {
                    'css/main.css': 'scss/main.scss'
                }
            }
        }, // sass
```

My scss file

```
@import 'susy';
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get this to work?
I got mine to work using grunt-sass and susy like this:

```
    sass: {
        options: {
            includePaths: ['node_modules/susy/sass'],
            require: 'susy',
            outputStyle: 'compressed',
            sourceMap: true
        },
        build: {
            files: {
                'stylesheets/css/styles.min.css': 'stylesheets/scss/styles.scss'
            }
        }

    },
```

And then I'm using `@import susy` in my styles.scss file.